# How to truncat inputstream and make as a pdf file?

Tags: java, android, pdf, io, filesystems

I am getting response as inputStream and then trying to get substring from File tag in 25th line to EOF in last but one line.
I am able to create a file using substring but while trying to open a file, it shows 'Can't display a pdf ( file is of invalid format)'.

Here is my InputStream from response,

```
--==QC9dJaqlij73THUaxjyjOO2b1x2NhroxulP3A5cicXZwetKPR8zfKp7AaxN7==
    Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=utf-8; 
    type="application/soap+xml"
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
    Content-ID: <SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding"     
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:http="http://tempuri.org/http.xsd" 
xmlns:wsdp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2006/02/devprof" 
xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" 
xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" 
xmlns:scnsvc="http://www.xerox.com/webservices/scanservice/2" 
xmlns:wscnx="http://schemas.xerox.com/office/wsd"><SOAP-ENV:Header></SOAP-
ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:Body><scnsvc:GetImageFileResponse><scnsvc:Image>
<scnsvc:Name>job:738.pdf</scnsvc:Name><scnsvc:Bytes><xop:Include 
href="cid:File"/></scnsvc:Bytes></scnsvc:Image>
<scnsvc:ImageFileStatus>FileReturned</scnsvc:ImageFileStatus>
</scnsvc:GetImageFileResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
--==QC9dJaqlij73THUaxjyjOO2b1x2NhroxulP3A5cicXZwetKPR8zfKp7AaxN7==
Content-Type: application/file
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <File>

%PDF-1.4
%øåÐÄÆ
4 0 obj
<< /Type /Page
/Parent 2 0 R
/Resources 3 0 R
/MediaBox [0 0 842 596]

   /Rotate 270
   /Contents 6 0 R
   endobj
   3 0 obj
   << /ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]

    /XObject << /XIPLAYER0 5 0 R

endobj

5 0 obj
<< /Length 111755
/Type /XObject
/Subtype /Image
/BitsPerComponent 8
/Width 2368
/Height 1655
/ColorSpace /DeviceGray
/Filter /DCTDecode
/DecodeParms << >>

endstream

endobj

1 0 obj
<< /Type /Catalog
/Pages 2 0 R
endobj

2 0 obj
<< /Type /Pages
/Kids [4 0 R]
/Count 1
endobj

7 0 obj
<< /CreationDate (D:20000123060407Z00'00')
/Creator (Xerox WorkCentre 5955)
/Producer (Xerox WorkCentre 5955)
endobj

xref
0 8
0000000000 65535 f 
0000112339 00000 n 
0000112389 00000 n 
0000000133 00000 n 
0000000016 00000 n 
0000000234 00000 n 
0000112185 00000 n 
0000112447 00000 n 

trailer
<< /Size 8
/Root 1 0 R
/Info 7 0 R
/ID [<ba62d01d5519b63d3984c820eb1dbc57> <ba62d01d5519b63d3984c820eb1dbc57>]
startxref
112576
%%EOF
--==QC9dJaqlij73THUaxjyjOO2b1x2NhroxulP3A5cicXZwetKPR8zfKp7AaxN7==--
```

Here is my code

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(inputStream));
String line = "";
StringBuilder filecontent = new StringBuilder();
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    filecontent.append(line);
}
bufferedReader.close();
String requiredString = filecontent.substring(filecontent.indexOf("<File>") 
    + 6, filecontent.indexOf("EOF")+3);

try {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Creating file...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    File filename = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), 
"abc123.pdf");
   FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    output.write(requiredString.getBytes());
    output.flush();
    output.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

    }
```

Please guide where I made wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are doing, but treating the stream as a series of bytes converted to chars and then trying to extract a PDF from that is probably not going to work. By the time you get the PDF data (if this is what you are doing) all those bytes have been turned into some set of chars for a given charset.

Comment: In other words: you cannot use readLine() to download a pdf file. You should read the bytes of the file in a byte[] buffer and directly save the readed bytes to file. You can use a loop doing so.

Comment: Already using an `InputStreamReader` can be destructive. Thus, please use functionalities to search in binaries and cut accordingly. Furthermore, you identify the end of a PDF by the characters "EOF". This is inappropriate: While there indeed must be an `%%EOF` at the end of a PDF (including or not including a line break thereafter!), this sequence may well also occur inside the PDF. Essentially your `InputStream` contains a MIME container. There should be lots of code for extracting attachments from MIME containers out there...